# Why is my Firebase project cloud messaging iOS configuration section blank?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to add FCM functionality to an iOS app in firebase. I am following the firebase guide for this, and in [this step](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_authentication_key) it explicitly states "In APNs authentication key under iOS app configuration, click the Upload button."

My problem is that there is literally NOTHING under my 'iOS app configuration'. So where and how exactly do I upload my APN key?

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue on my project as well.  I have no clue.

Comment: I reached out to Firebase support.  They said engineers are investigating the issue and that multiple users had reported a similar experience.

Comment: Same problem here. Is it still possible?

Answer (score 3):

Inside your project in the Firebase console, select the gear icon, select Project Settings, and then go first to the General tab. Be sure that there is an iOS app first.